# Add authentication to my own WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, access-token

I have searched so many things regarding customizing authentication to WebApi2
But I didn't get the Exact output. Anyone please give me a method to go my authentication process to my own webapi.

Comment: need some more detail....

Comment: IMO, you can read http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Comment: I have accessed a webapi with token based authentication but in that default asp.net DB has created but I have my own DB to my Webapi which I am developing for my app. I want access my webapi with my DB users table but I am not able to regeister an user with that table.